# Spivak, Ch. 20, Problem *4(i): Write down a sum which equals $\sin{1}$ with an error of less than $10^{-10^{10}}$.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, polynomials, taylor-expansion

In Chapter 20 of Spivak's *Calculus*, entitled "Approximation by Polynomial Functions", in problem 4(i) we are asked to find a polynomial that approximates $\sin{1}$ with an error of less than $10^{-10^{10}}$.

**Let me cut to the chase and tell you what my question is.**

As I show below, there are two very simple answers to this problem (and they are in the solution manual): a Taylor polynomial of order $10^{10^{10}}-1$, or even better, a Taylor Polynomial of order $10^{10}-1$.

I came up with a different solution that finds a minimum bound for the order of the polynomial as

$$10^{10}\frac{\log{10}}{\log{2}}-1\tag{3}$$

**My question is:** is this answer useful? Since this number is not a natural number, it seems that we'd need to figure out a natural number larger than this to find the Taylor Polynomial required to approximate $\sin{1}$. Is this easy to do?

**I will now go through all the steps involved in this problem, and show my attempted solution.**

If we write

$$f(x)=\sin{x}=P_{n,a}(x)+R_{n,a}(x)$$

where $P_{n,a}(x)$ is the Taylor polynomial of degree $n$ for $f$ at $a$, and $R_{n,a}(x)$ is the remainder term, then by Taylor's Theorem we have

$$\sin{x}=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{2n+1} \left [\sin^{(i)}{(a)}\frac{(x-a)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\right ]+\frac{\sin^{(2n+2)}{(t)}}{(2n+2)!}(x-a)^{2n+2}, t\in (a,x)$$

$$R_{2n+1,a}(x)=\frac{\sin^{(2n+2)}{(t)}}{(2n+2)!}(x-a)^{2n+2}, t\in (a,x)$$

$$R_{2n+1,0}(x)=\frac{\sin^{(2n+2)}{(t)}}{(2n+2)!}x^{2n+2}, t\in (0,x)$$

$$R_{2n+1,0}(1)=\frac{\sin^{(2n+2)}{(t)}}{(2n+2)!}, t\in (0,x)$$

$$\leq \frac{1}{(2n+2)!}$$

Therefore, we want

$$\frac{1}{(2n+2)!}<10^{-10^{10}}$$

$$\implies (2n+2)!>10^{10^{10}}$$

The solution manual has the following two solutions as possibilities

One immediate option is to have $2n+2=10^{10^{10}}$. This works and we have that

$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\frac{10^{10^{10}}-2}{2}}(-1)^{i}\frac{1}{i!}$$

is within $10^{-10^{10}}$ of $\sin{1}$.

Another option is to choose $2n+2=10^{10}$ "since $(10^{10})!$ is clearly larger than $10^{10^{10}}$".

In this case, we have

$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\frac{10^{10}-2}{2}}(-1)^{i}\frac{1}{i!}$$

(I missed this last solution though; [I asked another question about how to prove that $(10^{10})!$ is larger than $10^{10^{10}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4512915/how-do-we-show-that-1010-is-larger-than-101010))

**My solution is as follows**

For any $a>0$ and $\epsilon>0$ there is some $N$ such that $\frac{a^n}{n!}<\epsilon$ for $n>N$.

**Proof**

> Let $n\geq 2a$. Then
> $\frac{a^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}=\frac{a}{n+1}\frac{a^n}{n!}<\frac{1}{2}\frac{a^n}{n!}$.
>
> For any $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n_0\geq 2a$ we have
>
> $$\frac{a^{n_0+1}}{(n_0+1)!}<\frac{1}{2}\frac{a^n_0}{n_0!}$$
> $$\frac{a^{n_0+2}}{(n_0+2)!}=\frac{a}{n_0+2}\frac{a^{n_0+1}}{(n_0+1)!}<\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\frac{a^n_0}{n_0!}$$
>
> Thus
>
> $$\frac{a^{n_0+k}}{(n_0+k)!}<\frac{1}{2^k}\frac{a^{n_0}}{n_0!}\tag{1}$$
>
> Now, $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} 2^{-k}=0$. This means
>
> $$\forall \epsilon_1>0\ \exists N>0\ \forall k, k>N\implies
> > 2^{-k}<\epsilon_1$$
>
> Let $\epsilon_1=\frac{\epsilon n_0!}{a^{n_0}}$. Then $\exists N\
> > \forall k, k>N\implies 2^{-k}<\frac{\epsilon n_0!}{a^{n_0}}$. But from
> $(1)$ this means that
>
> $$\frac{a^{n_0+k}}{(n_0+k)!}<\epsilon$$

Note that the $N$ in the proof above is
$$2^{-k}<\epsilon \implies 2^k>\frac{1}{\epsilon}\implies k>\log_2(1/\epsilon)=N$$

Back to the main problem, let $2n=k$, where for the time being these numbers are real. Then we want

$$\frac{1}{(2+k)!}<10^{-10^{10}}=\epsilon$$

Let $\epsilon_1=\epsilon\cdot 2!$.

Then $\frac{1}{(2+k)!}<\epsilon$ if $k=2n>\log_2\left [ \frac{1}{\epsilon\cdot 2!} \right ]=\log_2 \left [ \frac{10^{10^{10}}}{2!} \right ]$

That is

$$n>\frac{1}{2}\log_2 \left [ \frac{10^{10^{10}}}{2!} \right ] \implies \frac{1}{(2n+2)!}<10^{-10^{10}}\tag{2}$$

Now, this lower bound for $n$ is not a natural number.

This chapter is about polynomial approximations, and as far as I have understood this is very practical chapter. With the initial two solutions, we had natural numbers and could compute the sum of polynomial terms with enough computing power.

In my proof, I found a minimum value for $n$ that is not a natural number. In fact it is

$$10^{10}\frac{\log{10}}{\log{2}}-1\tag{3}$$

which is not better than the solution in the solution manual of a Taylor polynomial of order $10^{10}-1$. However, I am curious to know if this answer is even acceptable in practical terms.

We'd have to compute the logarithmic values, I assume using polynomial approximation as well.

Assuming my solution is correct, is it a good answer? By that I mean, can we easily find a natural number larger than the number in $(3)$?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with an answer that is not a natural.  You have made some approximations and shown that a Taylor series with at least a number of terms is sufficient.  If your answer that at least $2.5$ terms was sufficient we could take one with $3$ terms.  We just round up one more time.  We can certainly calculate the value in $(3)$.  [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28log+10%2Flog+2%29*10%5E10-1) does it, for example.

Comment: @RossMillikan Wouldn't we have to also compute the logarithms to some desired accuracy, to then compute my answer? Seems like my answer requires a lot more resources to compute than the simpler solutions, correct? Those series on Alpha look quite complicated.

Comment: Yes, we have to compute the ratio of the logs to $10$ decimals so the error is less than $1$ after multiplying by $10^{10}$.  That is far easier than the calculation to $10^{10}$ decimals you are being asked for.  I just know that $\log_{10}2 \approx 0.30103$ and your ratio is the inverse of this, so I can get $5$ decimals from one division.  One iteration of Newton-Raphson should give $5$ more.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\sin1=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\!/(2k+1)!$, the error by truncating to $n$ terms is less in magnitude than $1/(2n+1)!$. Therefore, to reduce the error below $10^{-10^{10}}$, it is enough to ensure that $(2n+1)!>10^{10^{10}}$. Taking logarithms, this requires that $$\sum_{k=2}^{2n+1}\ln k>10^{10}\ln10.$$Now $\int_k^{k+1}\ln x\,\mathrm dx<\ln (k+1)$, because the logarithm is an increasing function. Hence $$\sum_{k=2}^{2n+1}\ln k>\int_1^{2n}\ln x\,\mathrm dx=2n(\ln2n-1)+1.$$It is therefore sufficient that $2n(\ln2n-1)> 10^{10}\ln10$. Consequently $n=6\times10^8$ is big enough.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin 1 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{2n+1} {1 \over (2n+1)!}$ which is alternating so
$|\sin 1 - \sum_{n=0}^N (-1)^{2n+1} {1 \over (2n+1)!} | \le {1 \over (2N+2)!} $.

You want $(2N+2)! > 10^{10^{10}}$ or $\log(2N+2)+\cdots + \log 2 + \log 1> 10^{10} \log 10$.

Thanks to John Bentin for pointing out an egregious error in my previous answer. A looser bound comes from $(2N+1) \log 2 \ge \log(2N+2)+\cdots + \log 2 + \log 1$ and
$4 = {\log 16 \over \log 2} > {\log 10 \over \log 2} $ which gives
$N > 2 \cdot 10^{10}$.

Comment: While it is clear to me that $\log(2N+2)+\cdots + \log 2 + \log 1> 10^{10} \log 10$ implies that $(2N+2)^2 > 10^{10} \log 10$, I don't see why the converse implication should hold.  Thus, while the constraint $N \ge 10^5 $ indeed suffices for  $N>{1\over2}10^5\sqrt{\log 10}$ and consequently $(2N+2)^2 > 10^{10} \log 10$ to hold, I don't see why  $\log(2N+2)+\cdots + \log 2 + \log 1> 10^{10} \log 10$ follows.

Comment: @JohnBentin You are correct, my estimate was incorrect.