# How do we show that $(10^{10})!$ is larger than $10^{10^{10}}$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, taylor-expansion

The question is simply: how do we show that $(10^{10})!$ is larger than $10^{10^{10}}$?

The context in which this question arose was in trying to find a polynomial approximation to $\sin{1}$ with an error of less than $10^{-10^{10}}$, the details of which are in [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4512913/spivak-ch-20-problem-4i-write-own-a-sum-which-equals-sin1-with-an-er).

In summary, if one knows that $(10^{10})!$ is larger than $10^{10^{10}}$, then it turns out a Taylor Polynomial of order $10^{10}$ is sufficient to get an error lower than $10^{-10^{10}}$.

Comment: One could also apply the Stirling approximation (which is rather popular here at MSE) to show that $$ (10^{10})! \ \ \sim \ \ \sqrt{2 \pi · 10^{10}} \ · \ \left(\frac{10^{10}}{e} \right)^{10^{10}} \ \sim \ \  2.5 · 10^5 \ · \  ( 10^{9.57}  )^{10^{10}} \ \ \sim \ \ 2.5 · 10^5 \ · \    10^{9.57·10^{10}} \ \ .  $$  In fact, it is already the case that $ \ n!  \ > \ 10^n  \ $ for $ \ n \ \ge \ 25 \ \ . $

Answer (score 8):

$10^{10^{10}}$ is the product of $10^{10}$ factors of $10$ while the first $\frac 12 \cdot 10^{10}$ factors of $(10^{10})!$ are larger than $10^2$ so have a product larger than $10^{10^{10}}$.

Answer (score 5):

$$\left(10^{10}\right)! = 100!\cdot\left(\prod\limits_{i=101}^{10^{10}}i\right) \gt 100!\cdot\left(\prod\limits_{i=101}^{10^{10}}100\right) = 100!\cdot 100^{10^{10}-100} = 100!\cdot 10^{2\cdot10^{10} - 200}$$ $$\gt 10^{2\cdot10^{10} - 200} = 10^{10^{10} + 10^{10} - 200} \gt 10^{10^{10}}$$

This uses the lemma that $10^{10} \gt 200$.

Answer (score 2):

Using algebra, you want to find when
$$(a^a)! \geq a^{a^a}$$ To make life easier because of the huge numbers, when is
$$f(a)=\log\Bigg[\frac{(a^a)!}{a^{a^a}}\Bigg] >0$$

By inspection or plotting, this is already true if $a>2$ since $f(2)=\log \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$.

More precisely, using Newton method, the zero of $f(a)$ is $1.83438$ which does not seem to be known by inverse symbolic calculators.

Answer (score 0):

For integer valued $a$, $a! > a^{10}$ for $a\geq 21$; ($ a= 10^{10}\geq  21$) .
$$a! = a(a-1)(a-2)(a-3) .... (a-19)...1 > a*[(a-1)(a-19)] *[(a-2)(a-18)]*...*[(a-9)(a-10)] > a [(a-1)(a-19)]^9 \geq a(2a-2)^9 > a^{10}.$$